# What happens if I drive without antifreeze in my car for a long time?

Tags: engine, antifreeze

Hello so i have a very specific question.
I was driving without antifreeze in my car for 3 months. The antifreeze low light turned on in june and i just tought it was broken and i drove like that till september. No other warning lights turned on and a few days ago i added antifreeze in my car and the light turned off. What are the chances i broke something?

Edit 1:
I also forgot to mention that i constantly monitored engine temp and it never went above average.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair! Just because the sensor stated the coolant was low, doesnt mean there wasn't any. If you didnt overheat and the vehicle isnt running bad, I'd suggest there's no issues.

Comment: Well, no issues apart from the OP needing to do regular checks and top things up...

Comment: "What happens if I drive without antifreeze in my car for a long time?" Corrosion of the cooling system will result doing this.

Comment: Thanks everyone for the tips and opinions. Ill be going to the mechanic on monday and will update you it there indeed was any damage.